# Customize label text in grid view template field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to show "N/A" text in grid view label if value is not available in database and if it is available, then the value should be displayed instead of "N/A".

How can I customize my label?

This is the code that I have written to get the value.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCineRunFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CineRunFrom") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Which `CineRunFrom` property value indicates that it's not available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
<asp:Label id="dada" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0}",string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CineRunFrom").ToString())?"N/A":Eval("CineRunFrom")) %>' ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this: `Text='<%# Eval("CineRunFrom")?? "N/A" %>'`

Comment: What type of the CineRunFrom property?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function in code behind & call it from HTML code, check sample code below.

**Code**

```
Private Function GetDisplayText(ByVal CineRunFrom As String) As String
      'Do whatever you want here and return text to dispaly as required
End Function
```

**HTML**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCineRunFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDisplayText(Eval("CineRunFrom")) %>'></asp:Label>
```